Will running a dehumidifier in a basement impact room temperature?
Would a dehumidifier in a basement change the temperature of the room/basement?

Toshiba 45 Pint 115-Volt Dehumidifier
Continuous operation mode; draining into floor drain
400 square ft basement; 8 ft ceilings; concrete floor and walls
800 sq ft house; built in 1929; 1.5 stories
Greater Toronto Area, Ontario, Canada

My basement is hot. I'm wondering if the dehumidifier is warming it up.

What's your concern, exactly? What problem are you trying to solve?

What I find really strange about this (on Home Depot site via link but also on Toshiba site) is (a) it is "115-Volt". That changed to 120V around 40 years ago, and I assure you that dehumidifier was designed much more recently; (b) nowhere that I could find listed the power usage (e.g., Watts) or current (Amps). This is a heat pump, but like a refrigerator rather than an air conditioner because input and output are both indoors. So it should be a net balance on cooling vs. heating except for the heat generated from the compressor, etc. - which is unknown without knowing the power/current used.

@isherwood My basement is hot. I'm wondering if the dehumidifier is warming it up.

I run one all summer in Minnesota. I don't think it has a significant effect on room temperature. It doesn't really matter, though, because it's a necessity to prevent mustiness.

They are very poor room heaters(maybe in a tiny cupboard with the door close).  A hot basement/room will have other causes, warm air entering from somewhere, sunlight beating down on a wall.

Note that when a mini split system is running dehumidifying mode, the heat removes to condense the water is usually being pumped outside. However, there may be a heating coil to speed up melting the frost that has been collected so it can be drained away; if so, that may offset the heat removed to some degree. Note that one of the implications is that mini splits can only dehumidify when they are in cooling mode; if you are running it to heat, it cannot dehumidify. This solution may be a separate dehumidifier, or to temporarily change modes.

@crip659  Actually they are more efficient heaters than a "real" electric heater.

@MikeB, yes, they certainly are more efficient (in physics/engineering terms). They're not particularly effective which tends to lead to a bit of confusion.

My basement is finished with insulation, but the top of the stairs is open and I'm not far from you, heat is still off and it's early October.  Running the dehumidifier for 24 hours increased the basement temp 5F.  In the summer the difference is usually much higher, probably because we don't A/C the house which would reduce the workload on the dehumidifier if we had A/C running.

Yes. Or maybe. It depends on what ventilation or circulation practices you have in place.
A dehumidifier works by cooling a coil, on which water vapor then condenses. In order to cool something, you usually have to heat something else. In this case it's ultimately air exhausted out the back or side of the unit, just as with a refrigerator. This can raise room temperature if you don't have air circulation preventing it.
However, in my experience the net effect is a wash. The feel of dryer air is cooler, so even if the room warms a degree or two, it'll feel the same or cooler due to the improved function of body sweat.

That's very true in a warm humid environment.  Those of us using dehumidifiers in cool damp climates are glad of the warmth (and the exhaust from mine does feel slightly warm especially on low fan speed)

In order to cool something you have to heat something else, first law of thermodynamics, and you're going to end up with more heat, second law of thermodynamics.

A dehumidifier converts vapor to liquid water - that releases heat.
It also has a electric motor  that also releases heat.
It's basically the inverse of a swamp cooler.

We can work out how much heat. The latent heat of vaporisation of water is 2,260kJ/kg, so per litre (=1kg) of water condensed (at room temperature) you get 2.26 MJ (about 0.63kWh in more familiar units). The specific heat capacity of air is 1.005 kJ/kg/°C or about 1.3 kJ/m³/°C. The biggest question is the size of the room. Mine is in a room approx 10×4×2.5m (100m³).  Excluding losses my room could warm by 17°C for each litre condensed. In practice that takes 12 hours, in which time there's a lot of air exchange with the rest of the house, heat soaks into the walls, etc. so in practice not much

@ChrisH if you know the power draw of the dehumidifier, the calculation will be much simpler.  The power used by the dehumidifier will all eventually be turned into heat.

@Mark, No.  You have to add that to the latent heat.  But the power consumption is far less than the latent heat recovered (hence my ignoring the electrical power, and the order and emphasis of Jasen's points)

Yes for sure.    The more the humidifier works the greater the energy output.   Unless it is dissipating the energy out a window and in only in that direction your basement will be warmer.
In a closed basement if you run fans continuously it will get warmer.   We have ran fans to get rid of water and if the thermostat is on the first floor it is quite normal for the basement to be 2-3 degrees warmer after a day of running heavy fans.

This is the best answer. Unless heat is moved outside the building a self-contained dehumidifier simply moves heat from the air into the water that condenses into the drip pan. The mechanics of the dehumidifier requires electricity to operate. Some of that electricity will be converted to work (turning the compressor) but most of the electricity will be converted to heat.

Yes, the dehumidifier compressor will exhaust heat in the room. However not much, more like a 150 Watt light bulb.
The main change in the temperature will be in the Feels like
They have "Feels Like" in the weather forecast.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact thank you for your concern, the compressor consumes 400 Watt for the motor. Estimated no more than 30% is converted into heat.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact if all the 400 Watt would go in to heat and not motor function, that would be very bad design

@Traveler That's not how efficiency works. All energy ends up as heat. All of that 400W will end up as heat, either in the air, or in the water. Just because 75% of it has done some useful work on the way there doesn't change the fact that it will ultimately be heat. a 400W humidifier will put 400W of heat into the environment. (Don't forget that the phase change of the water will also release latent heat)

I'm from 2024, what's a "light bulb"? :)

Just wanted to underline what @SiHa said - the process of condensing water releases stored heat, so something like 105% of the electric energy 'used' is converted to local heat - so an enclosed de-humidifier is a better room heater than an electric heater.

@SiHa as per your logic, the circuit breaker and the wires that carry the 400 W will also heat up

@Traveler They do heat up, but by an insignificant amount by comparison. Not sure what point you're trying to make there. The circuit breaker and the wires aren't consuming the energy, the dehumidifier is.

@Traveler :D No. That's not how electricity works, either. Given a 12AWG cable, a device pulling 400W will dissipate about 17W per 1000ft of cable. Sure, they heat slightly, which is why wiring regulations ususally state different current-carrying capacities of cable, depending on whether it's surface-mounted or buried in insulation. The temperature increase in a room due to this, though, would be negligible.
